# Using the correct codes with setlocale

Tags: mfc, setlocale

I have had a look at [setlocale](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99tb11d.aspx) but I am struggling to find what I am looking for.

In my code I have:

```
void CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::SetLocale()
{
    CString strLang[NUM_LANGUAGES] =
    {
        _T("eng"), _T("deu"), _T("esp"), _T("ita"),
        _T("plk"), _T("fra"), _T("ptb"), _T("nld"),
        _T("sve"), _T("slv"), _T("csy"), _T("fin"),
        _T("dan"), _T("ukr"), _T("rus"),
        _T("eng"), /*_T("fpo") Tagalog */
        _T("eng"), /* Haitian Creole */
        _T("eng"), /* Afrikaans */
        _T("sqi"),
        _T("chs"), /* Chinese (Simplified) */
        _T("hrv"),
        _T("trk"),
        _T("eng"),  /* Twi */
        _T("swk"),  // AJT v11.3.4
        _T("eng"),  // _T("eti") Estonian AJT v12.0.5
        _T("rom"),  // Romanian AJT v12.0.8
        _T("ell"),  // Greek AJT v13.0.0
        _T("bgr"),  // Bulgarian AJT v13.0.2
        _T("eng"),  // Malagasy AJT v14.0.4
        _T("ara"),  // Arabic AJT v16.0.0
        _T("ind"),  // Indonesian AJT v16.0.2
        _T("hin"),  // Hindi AJT v16.0.7
        _T("tai"),  // Tamil AJT v16.1.0
        _T("vit"),  // Vietnamese v16.1.1
        _T("eng"),  // Zulu AJT v16.1.6
        _T("eng"),  // Gun AJT v17.0.9
        _T("ln-CG"),  // Lingala v17.0.9
        _T("ptg")   // Portuguese Portugal v17.1.0
        // Add more languages here
    };

    _tsetlocale(LC_ALL, strLang[m_eLanguage - LANGUAGE_ENGLISH]);
}
```

This has done and always works OK. Dates format correct after making this call.

But looking at the links provided with the aforementioned help topic I can't find codes like `ptb` etc. listed. Only `pt-BR`.

I assume my codes are still valid and are they documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[setlocale](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99tb11d.aspx) expects a locale name as documented under [Locale Names, Languages, and Country/Region Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hzz3tw78.aspx). A locale can be identified by [locale name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/dd373814.aspx):

> A [locale](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318716.aspx) name is based on the language tagging conventions of RFC 4646 (Windows Vista and later), and is represented by [LOCALE_SNAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373858.aspx). Generally, the pattern <language>-<REGION> is used. Here, language is a lowercase ISO 639 language code. The codes from ISO 639-1 are used when available. Otherwise, codes from ISO 639-2/T are used.
>
> [...]
>
> If the locale is a neutral locale (no region), the [LOCALE_SNAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373858.aspx) value follows the pattern <language>.

A complete list of ISO 639-2 three-letter language codes is published at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-2_codes).